# How to build an Android View with clock-like rotation?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-custom-view, custom-view

I found the example of what I want to build.
The idea is to have list items, displayed in circle. One item could be active and display info about it. Click on the item rotates this circle to the position of active item. Also you are able to rotate the view in this circle scroll.
I've never met such component, so that is why I can't use correct words describing it.
Do you have any ideas? Please, share with me.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3LVy.png)

No tries, only research. Expect to create a smooth good looking view.